# objective c frustrate me whats with pointers?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I know my issue has to do with pointers (obj-c noob), but how can go about getting this, which I know is wrong.

```
double *lat = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double *lng = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude;
```

Get an error using suggestions below when I try to use this "Expected ) before CLLocationDegress"

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)findNextTwentyFiveRemote:(CLLocationDegrees *)latitude withLong:    (CLLocationDegrees *)longitude withLastIncrementNum:(int *)lastPostIdAsString;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: Importantly, it's not clear why you would want a pointer to a double.

Comment: Thats it I don't I am trying to get lat and lng as double so i can use them in a function.

Comment: Can you please give the full function call and the error? Also, why are you using `latitude` and `longitude` instead of `lat` and `lng`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the latitude and longitude properties, then all you need to do is drop the pointer declaration:

```
double lat = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude;
double lng = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude;
```

Since `latitude` and `longitude` are just doubles, not pointers of any kind (they're not objects), you don't declare the variable storing them as a pointer.

Comment: Expected ) before CLLocationDegress. when I try to use it 

+ (NSMutableArray *)findNextTwentyFiveRemote:(CLLocationDegrees *)latitude withLong:    (CLLocationDegrees *)longitude withLastIncrementNum:(int *)lastPostIdAsString;

Comment: I have a sneaky feeling your problem isn't with your `lat` and `lng`, but rather with the declaration of that function (or some previous code). Can you post more of the file it came from? Also, are you sure you're including the MapKit headers as needed?

Answer (score 0):

```
double lat = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.latitude,
       lng = self.lastKnownLocation.coordinate.longitude;

// Later, when you want double pointers for some reason...
function_that_takes_double_pointers( & lat, & lng );
```

Comment: Maybe I'm just cranky, but really? A two-variable initialization across two lines just so you can save yourself from typing `double` twice?